# Cannot start new activity using Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two activity `MainActivity.java` and `ListActivity.java`.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    button.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            startAc(view);
        }
    });
}
public void startAc(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

As soon as I click the button, the Emulator gives an error **Application has stopped working.**

Is the use of Intent inappropriate?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this If I had to guess, your problem is that Android already has a class named `ListActivity`, and you are getting your two `ListActivity` classes confused.

Comment: have you declare the new Activity on the ManifesT?

Comment: @ItzikSamara yes its all been declared in the Manifest.

Comment: Please post the Cat-log

Comment: @ItzikSamara
`E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sujin.fraglistrevision/com.example.sujin.fraglistrevision.ListActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
E/AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)`

Comment: mate your error is not here but on the other Activity when you start your Adapter please edit your post with the ListActiviytiy Code

Answer (score 1):

Try this code your wrong import your are import adapterview please import correct `View.OnClickListener`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){

    Intent intent = new Intent(getapplicationcontext(), ListActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
                }
    });
   }
```

***Add Your Manifest this line after closing  first activity***

```
   <activity android:name=".ListActivity.class"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing `this` to `MainActivity.this`. Also make sure every activity is defined in manifest